# Set interpreter for Python program

Tags: python, virtualenv, interpreter

I have one virtual environment. How can I set the virtual python interpreter for my python file which is there in the virtual env file??? I cant find any solution.

Example: I want to set this file to work with the Python interpreter in the virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

I install venv like this on ubuntu 18.04

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
$ /usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv --prompt="venv_name" venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv_name) $ pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
(venv_name) $ pip install numpy matplotlib pandas xlrd PyQt5
```

In vscode
[click on the bottom, then choose the venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLp8t.png)

Comment: I hope to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Every virtual environment has a Python executable (as a link or as a copy) in its bin directory.

So on a unix-ish system (Linux, Mac, etc) do the following:

1. Locate your virtual env. Say it is in the directory `/home/me/.venvs/myvenv`.
2. Then in this direcorty find the interpretr at the path `bin/python` and note the full path (In the sample case `/home/me/.venvs/myvenv/bin/python`)
3. In your python file add *as the first line* (i.e. on top of your python code):

   ```
    #!/home/me/.venvs/myvenv/bin/python
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the exact path of the python which is present in the Virtual enviroment.

**For Example:**
**Your Virtual Environment path:** `/home/user/myEnv/`

**Your python bin location will be:** `/home/user/myEnv/bin/python`

You need to run  `/home/user/myEnv/bin/python <filename>.py`